# Android: What's the best way to stop serving your app to chromebooks?

Tags: android, chromebook

I have an app that's having some issues on chromebooks and want to stop serving the app to those devices. What's the best way to prevent chromebooks from getting the app?

From the docs there seems to be these solutions:
https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/manifest.html

> 1) Exclude specific devices in the Google Play Console.
>
> 2) Filter devices with no touchscreen hardware by explicitly declaring android.hardware.touchscreen as being required in order to install your app.

I don't have a chromebook on me, so I can't really test. Are those the best ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the best way to prevent chromebooks from getting the app?

There is no "best".

The reliable but difficult to manage approach is the first option you cited: block them in the Play Developer Console. The problem is that the list of Chrome OS devices changes frequently, and you may miss devices.

The second option that you cited will not work, as there are plenty of Chrome OS devices that have touchscreens. In fact, a majority might have touchscreens, as they are fairly common among Chromebooks.

[The page that you cited](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/manifest.html) lists many features that Chrome OS devices lack. If Chrome OS devices lacking one of those features is the source of your problem, add the appropriate `<uses-feature>` element. For example, if you need NFC, add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>` to your manifest. That will prevent your app from being installed on *any* incompatible device, including phones or tablets that lack NFC.

If the issue is something else, ideally you fix the problem, as the problem may not be unique to Chrome OS.

In the end, you're welcome to pretend that your app needs one of those features, just to stay off of Chrome OS devices. For example, as noted above, `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>` would keep you off of Chrome OS devices. However, it *also* keeps you off of phones and tablets that lack NFC.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1**

There is not 100% correct but it can exclude Chromebook and tablet from downloading the app, by adding this line in manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true"/>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
```

**Solution 3**

You can exclude the Chromebook devices in Google Play Console > Device Catalog > Filter Chromebook by 'form factor' > Exclude

Comment: "Solution 3", excluding by form factor worked for me.